# Android auto complete and passwords

Tags: passwords, android

I have an Android phone and when I enter a password in a password field (bank application or other), the auto complete system proposes to complete the password.

I expected password not to be saved by the auto complete system. I think that's a crazy security issue.

Is it the expected behavior here? Is it possible to clear the auto complete data?

Comment: Are you using the default android keyboard?

Comment: I guess I use it since I never changed something related to keyboard why?

Comment: Different keyboards have different autocomplete settings - they can each have their own database of autocomplete strings. I'd be surprised at the built in one saving strings entered in password fields, but not at some third party ones doing so.

Comment: Right - I'm also very surprised. I thought the auto complete was smarter...

Comment: Just to be sure, you do not use an ordinary word as your password? If your password is "firetruck" it might pop up just because it is in the dictionary. And you have not written it somewhere else (in a note to yourself, by mistake in a username field) that would cause it to be saved in the dictionary?

Comment: @Anders Good point. My password is very complicated and is not a real word at all.

Answer (score 1):

Device manufacturers make changes to the original Android OS(in some cases, to a large extent). I guess your manufacturer introduced this "feature" to help you auto-complete your passwords.

Or maybe they simply forgot to check for the password field and are simply storing each string in their database.

It is definitely not desirable to have your passwords stored. You should check, if feasible, another model from the same manufacturer, preferably with the same firmware, if it exhibits the same behavior.

It is usually possible to clear the auto-complete data. Go to `Settings>Apps>Keyboard`, and hit the `Clear Data` button, it should do the trick.

You can also switch to some another keyboard from Play Store. It would be wise to download it from some reputable vendor.

Also, check for firmware updates in your device. Chances are this issue might have been reported, and they might have fixed in the next firmware.